# Weird issue with valueForKeyPath:@"@max.totalSteps", is this bug in iOS platform code?

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I spent few hours in debugging this issue, and hence posting this, in case if you have expert advice/clue.

Here is the code where the problem is:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plot" ofType:@"json"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSInteger minSteps = [dict[@"steps"] valueForKeyPath:@"@min.totalSteps"];
NSInteger maxSteps = [dict[@"steps"] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.totalSteps"];
NSLog(@"Min Steps = %@", minSteps);
NSLog(@"Max Steps = %@", maxSteps);
```

JSON contents provided below, the above code expected to produce **minSteps** to be "**0**" (**zero**), and **maxSteps** to be "**710**".

However above code producing the following out out.

**Min Steps = 0
 Max Steps = 90**

**Why is max value found to be "90"??**

**Any clues are appreciated?**

Contents of plot.json file:

```
{
    steps =     (
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 75;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 184;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 113;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 90;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 11;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 386;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 282;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 22;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 42;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 710;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 200;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 111;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 12;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 49;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 67;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 104;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 55;
        }
    );
}
```

Providing Debugger output per request:
PS: Sorry for the length of the JSON, with duplication, as this is close to the real time data.

```
(lldb) po dict
{
    steps =     (
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 75;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 184;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 113;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 90;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 11;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 386;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 282;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 22;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 42;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 710;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 200;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 111;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 12;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 49;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 67;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 104;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 0;
        },
                {
            totalSteps = 55;
        }
    );
}

(lldb) po [dict[@"steps"] valueForKeyPath:@"@min.totalSteps"];
0

(lldb) po [dict[@"steps"] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.totalSteps"];
90

(lldb) po minSteps
0

(lldb) po maxSteps
90

(lldb)
```

@Matt, Thanks again. I have also found solution that was working:
For other benefit I am providing the code that works well.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plot" ofType:@"json"];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSMutableDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonParsingError];
NSInteger minSteps = [dict[@"steps"] valueForKeyPath:@"@min.totalSteps"];
NSInteger maxSteps = [dict[@"steps"] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.totalSteps"];
NSLog(@"Min Steps = %@", minSteps);
NSLog(@"Max Steps = %@", maxSteps);
```

However, please note, provided JSON structure is not quite correct as well, requires few modification, to be accepted by NSJSONSerialization parser.

Here is modified file with acceptable format:

```
{
    “steps” :     (
                {
            “totalSteps” : 0,
        },
...
```

If you see problem like this:

```
(lldb) po jsonParsingError
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No string key for value in object around character 6.) UserInfo=0x109875d50 {NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 6.}
```

Please check validity of JSON formatting. And make sure your file is not in RTF format, etc...

Comment: The JSON is irrelevant, since it is not what `valueForKeyPath` is being sent to. You need to log (and show us) `dict`.

Comment: @matt, thank for quick comments, the dict is the NSDictionary created from json file. Anyways, I am providing debugger out put for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when your file is turned into a dictionary, `steps` is ending up as an array of dictionaries where `totalSteps` is the key and the value is a *string*. From a string point of view, `"90"` is the largest (because it begins with the *letter* `"9"`, which comes later in the "alphabet" than any other digit; the digits, as characters, run from `"0"` to `"9"`).

And the reason for *that* is that you are reading the file as a *.plist* - you are not reading it as JSON at all. `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath]` interprets the file as a *.plist*. If you want it interpreted as JSON, read it as an NSData and then use the JSON methods (NSJSONSerialization) to convert it to Cocoa objects.

One must not imagine that the file will be read as JSON merely because its name ends in "json". `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` does only one thing: it reads a file as a `.plist`. Your file is just making it in the door, because it can be understood as an "old-style property list": see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001012-BBCBDBJE. There are no numbers in an old-style property list; only strings. In a way, you were unlucky; it would have been better for you if the attempt to read the file as a property list had failed! But unfortunately NSDictionary was able to interpret it as an old-style property list.

Comment: interesting, let me check.

Comment: +1 Makes perfect sense, that was the reason it worked fine when the response received from Cloud (APIs) worked well. I was working with Core Plots, and wanted local JSON, for speed of development to avoid network round trips, and hence landed into this situation.

Comment: Yes, you identification problem, and suggested solution worked.